# Nested promises and catch block

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have the below code, where i make a asynchronous call inside as shown by the comments. I am seeing that in case of error during execution of the async call, the console statements in the outermost catch block do not execute if I do not have a inner catch block.

So, if i have the inner catch block, the console statements in the outermost catch block execute but if i remove the inner catch block the console statements in the outermost catch block do not execute.

is this the expected behvaiour and if yes why does this happen? Any clarifiction as to why this is happening will be really helpful.

```
    printInfo(filter, counter).then(function(result) {
      let worksheet = tableauViz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet().getWorksheets().get('Filter');
      //Async call 
      worksheet.applyFilterAsync('test', ['hello', 'world'], 'replace').then(promiseTimeout(filter.delay, counter), function(err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }).then(function(counter) {
         //more processing
      }, function(err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }).catch(function(resp){ // inner catch
      });
    }, function(err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }).catch(function(resp){ // outer most catch
      console.error('in catch block');
      console.error(resp);
    });
```

Console statements in catch block only execute if there is a inner catch block to the code which makes aysnc call.

Thanks.

Comment: There's almost never a good reason to nest promises...and why the second callback .then all over the place that does nothing but rethrow?

Comment: I don’t think your reasoning is right. Probably just a misattribution. Can you setup a runnable code snippet with same effect but simplified structure to verify the case?